# Enumerating in table cell breaks table in bottom right

Tags: tables, longtable, enumerate

So I'm writing an enumeration in my textual use case table and it seems to be the issue breaking my table in the bottom right. Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

The latex code I'm using is as follows:

```
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{white}
\begin{longtable}{ | p{4cm} p{8cm} | }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    \multicolumn{2}{| l |}{\textbf{Use Case: UserAccess}}\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
    \textbf{Element} & \textbf{Description}\\
    \hline
    ID & Use Case 1\\
    Description & Users must securely login to use the program\\
    Primary Actors & Network Administrator\\
    Secondary Actors & None\\
    Preconditions & The user has access defined by the secure access policy\\
    Main Flow &
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item{User inputs login details}
        \item{\textbf{Include: Authenticate}}
        \item{If details are incorrect, user is asked to re-enter details}
    \end{enumerate}\\
    Postconditions & User is granted access to program\\
    Alternate Flows: None\\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the problem? That you forgot an `&` in the last row or something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by a missing column separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Furthermore, you have unwanted horizontal and vertical spacings at the top and bottom of the row with the enumerate environment. Here is how to avoid them using `enumitem`. Not you shouldn't use the `center` environment for tables, but the `\centering` directive, and none of them for longtables, which are automatically centred.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{ | p{4cm}p{8cm}|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!10}
  \multicolumn{2}{| l |}{\textbf{Use Case: UserAccess}} \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{gray!25}
  \textbf{Element} & \textbf{Description} \\
  \hline
  ID & Use Case 1 \\
  Description & Users must securely login to use the program \\
  Primary Actors & Network Administrator \\
  Secondary Actors & None \\
  Preconditions & The user has access defined by the secure access policy \\
  Main Flow &
  \begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt, leftmargin = *, nosep, itemsep = 2pt, before = \vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after =\vspace*{-\baselineskip} ]
    \item{User inputs login details}
    \item{\textbf{Include: Authenticate}}
    \item{If details are incorrect, user is asked to re-enter details}
  \end{enumerate} \\
  Postconditions & User is granted access to program \\
  Alternate Flows: None & \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]